# CakePHP View with json format

Tags: json, cakephp, mobile-application

I 'm going to make a CakePHP application which collaborates with a mobile application. Mobile application is going to query CakePHP app to check if some vouchers are valid or not. I need to change some of my views such that their outputs be in json format in order to be parsed by mobile application easily.
To be specific if mobile app calles `example.com/vouchers/check/1234` Cake should return something like this as response: `{"validity":"valid"}` or  `{"validity":"invalid"}` which is the result of checking the validity of voucher with id 1234.

Comment: Thats pretty much what my talk today at CakeFest was about: http://slides.com/marks-1/cakephp-and-ajax#/ and [ajax-and-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/).

Comment: That would be a nice talk! :D

Comment: Sry, the URL changed: http://de.slideshare.net/markfabianscherer/cakephp-andajax

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should use extensions when you expect non HTML responses (JSON in this case)
So request

```
/vouchers/check/1234.json
```

and use the JsonView as per docs and as per [ajax-and-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) tutorial.

#### To sum it up:

Use this to allow json extension being enabled:

```
Router::parseExtensions();
Router::setExtensions(array('json', ...));
```

Don't forget to include the RequestHandler component in the controllers $components list.

Add this to your action:

```
$data = array(
    'validity' => ...,
);
$this->set(compact('data')); // Pass $data to the view
$this->set('_serialize', 'data'); // Let the JsonView class know what variable to use
```

Comment: would you please update your answer? Link answers are not suitable for stackoverflow since they may change over time.